# Microsoft's strncat reads bytes beyond source buffer boundaries

Tags: c, pageheap

I observe an interesting problem with the Microsoft implementation of `strncat`. It touches 1 byte beyond the source buffer. Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char dstBuf[1024];
    char* src = malloc(112);
    memset(src, 'a', 112);
    dstBuf[0] = 0;
    strncat(dstBuf, src, 112);
}
```

`strncat` reads 1 byte after 112 byte block. So if you are unlucky enough to get allocation on an invalid page boundary, your application crashes. Large applications can crash intermittently in such places. (Note that such condition can be simulated with *gflags PageHeap* setting; block size has to be divisible by pointer size for proper alignment.)

Is this the expected behavior or a bug? Any links confirming that? (I read several descriptions of `strncat` but they can be interpreted both ways depending on your initial set of mind...)

**Update** (to answer questions about evidence): 
I apologize if it is not clear from the text above, but this is an experimental fact. I observe intermittent crashes in an application at `strncat` reading address src+srcBufSize. In this small example run with *gflags PageHeap* on crash reproduces consistently (100%). So as far as I can see the evidence is very solid.

**Update2** (info on compiler)
MS Visual Studio 2005 Version 8.0.50727.867. 
Build platform: 64 bit release (no repro for 32 bit). 
OS used to repro the crash: Windows Server 2008 R2.

**Update 3** The problem also reproduces with a binary built in MS Visual Studio 2012 11.0.50727.1

**Update 4** [Link to issue on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800199/strncat-reads-bytes-outside-of-source-buffer-range); [link to discussion on MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bbdc440-f8d0-48a8-b1a8-08f21aa9e4f5/strncat-reads-bytes-outside-of-source-buffer-range#3ec313ff-4373-4615-aed1-9a13300693f2)

**Update 5** The problem will be fixed in the next VS release. No fix is planned for old versions. See the "Microsoft Connect" link above.

Comment: What's your evidence for this claim?

Comment: I would love to look at your binary that behaves like this. Also, what version of compiler / library are you using?

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: Binary http://sdrv.ms/17rN1cF

Comment: I asked for evidence, not an executable. Nobody is going to execute an unknown .exe from an untrusted source, if they have any conception of computer security whatsoever. What's your *evidence?*

Comment: @EJP I was replying to OP who explicitly asked for binary. I guess the OP can view disassembler without running or set up a safe sand box. I updated the question to elaborate on evidence.

Comment: So, if `src` points to a non NUL-terminated array of pointers whose size is a multiple of 8 other than 0, the dword just beyond the array is read, altough the value read is unused. `mov    (%rdx),%rax; sub    $0x8,%r8; jb     0x400011a7` ← I can think of a couple of ways to change that, at the expense of performance.

Comment: @OP: so you cannot reproduce it on 32-bit. Can you share a 32-bit binary?

Comment: @ninjalj: Done. I put it in the same share.

Comment: Changing `jb` to `jbe` works, but then the final qword copy is made byte by byte. Apropos the 32-bit version, while it's based on the same idea, the details differ quite a bit. In particular, the aligned-[qd]word-concatenation loop uses a dword counter and exits on zero on the 32-bit version, while on the 64-bit version a byte-counter is used and it exits on below zero (as I said, it could have been on below or equal to zero, the 64-bit version has fallback code for up to 8 final bytes).

Comment: Sinking `mov (%rdx),%rax` after the `jb 0x400011a7` also works, but some of the following instructions depend on `%rax`, which may cause a performance degradation. In summary, I agree it's a bug.

Comment: Didn't Microsoft already fix this in 2008 or 2009? See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956420 and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=19141. So why is the bug still present in VS 2012?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey:  Note that that fix was for strncpy, not strncat.  This question is asking about strncat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `strncat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncat) states:

> **src**   -   pointer to the null-terminated byte string to copy from

Therefore, the implementation can assume that the `src` input parameter is in fact NUL-terminated, even if it is longer than `count` characters.

For further confirmation, [Microsoft's own documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbyd7s1y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) states:

> *strSource*
>
> > Null-terminated source string.

On the other hand, the [actual C standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) states something like:

> The `strncat` function appends not more than `n` characters (a null character and
>   characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the end of
>   the string pointed to by `s1`.

As pointed out in the comments below, this identifies the second parameter `s2` as an *array* and not a NUL-terminated string. However, this is still ambiguous with respect to the original question, because this documentation describes the ultimate effect on `s1`, rather than the behaviour of the function when reading from `s2`.

This could of course be settled with respect to the *specific* Microsoft implementation by consulting the C Runtime Library source code.

Comment: Not sure if I'm buying this.  It says "The **strncat** function appends, at most, the first *count* characters of *strSource* to *strDest*."

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: That's the resulting *behaviour*, but the input `src` string is nevertheless expected to be null-terminated.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - If you supply a non-null terminated string to perform a concatenation on what do you expect? This answer is perfect

Comment: The input string is expected to be null-terminated in case it is shorter than `count.` There is no language there that says it can read beyond `count` characters

Comment: I saw Microsoft documentation. I do not think it is clear enough. As I wrote, the interpretation depends on your initial set of mind about the subject. Here is a different link that does not mention null-termination: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/

Comment: @glagolig: Your link says "C string". C strings are always NUL-terminated.

Comment: @Greg I disagree. There's no reason it should ever read more than `count` characters.  [`strncat(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) says `"The strncat() function is similar, except that * it will use at most n bytes from src; and
* src does not need to be null-terminated if it contains n or more bytes."`

Comment: In fact, I can't even come up with a valid implementation that would care if the string was null-terminated. (as far as not overrunning `count` - how/why would it?)

Comment: @EdHeal `char src[3] = { 'a', 'a', 'a' }; char dst[100]; dst[0] = '\0'; strncat(dst, src, 3); printf("%s\n", dst);` I would expect this to function correctly, and print three `a` characters and not overrun any buffers.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: You're making reference to a specific (glibc) implementation of `strncat`, which is not the Microsoft implementation to which the OP refers.

Comment: @GregHewgill Right to show that what you're saying doesn't make sense. I've also cited another piece of documentation that says the OP's behavior *shouldn't* happen. The OP asked if what he was seeing was a bug... if the code he's showing touches `src[112]` then I'd say yes, his libc has a bug.

Comment: @GregHewgill: that conflicts with the C standard which treats the source operand as an array: _The  strncat() function shall append not more than n bytes (a null byte and bytes that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by s2 to the end of the string pointed to by s1._

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks for that, I've updated my answer with that info.

Comment: While the standard says nothing of the internal implementation of `strnlen`, the runtime library has no business accessing bytes past the end of the array specified by (start=`s2`, length=`n`). At least not unless it knows the array to be padded e.g: to dword size.

Comment: I accepted the answer since it has a reference to C standard. Now I think what I observe is a bug. Our code builds on several different platforms, developers cannot possibly review CRT sources on all platforms for every string function.

Answer (score 2):

`s2` is **not** a "string" in `strncat(s1, s2, n)`.

So if Microsoft is reading pass `n` bytes, it is not C11 compliant.

C11 7.24.2.3.1 `strcat()` mentions
"appends a copy of the **string** pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null character) to the end of the string pointed to by s1".

C11 7.24.2.3.2 `strncat` says
"The strncat function appends not more than n characters (a null character and characters that follow it are not appended) from the **array** pointed to by s2 to the end of the string pointed to by s1.  ...  A terminating null character is always appended to the result"

Clearly in the `strncat` case, `s2` is viewed as an "array" with a string-like limitations on how much is appended to `s1`.  Thus during the concatenation, this is no need to inspect `s2` more than what is absolutely needed.  The final written `\0` comes from code, not `s2`.

Don't know about the older C99 standard.

Answer (score 1):

English is an imperfect language, more so than C.

The documentation says "at **most** n characters" (my emphasis).  There is no evidence to indicate that strncat copies more than 112 characters.  What makes you believe it does?

The code of strncat might index past an offset of 112, but not actually reference offset 113 which could cause a storage fault.  This ptr behavior is defined as acceptable in K&R.

Finally, again this is an English/reasoning problem, the documentation probably does say null terminated string.  But really, isn't it redundant to say a string is null terminated?  They are by definition, otherwise they would be an array of characters.  So, the documentation is being vague and non-specific.  The programmer is left to read between the lines.  Software documentation are not legal tomes, they are descriptions that are meant to be understood by someone practiced in the art.

Comment: _Software documentation are not legal tomes_ ← but standards are indeed somewhat like legal tomes, and the C standard treats the source argument as an array. `strn*` functions are designed to work with _fixed size records_, so they don't behave exactly as if their subject matter were just strings.

Comment: @ninjalj, I agree with you that they are fixed size records and n determines the length of that record. C is allowed/defined to index 1 past the end of an array, which is why `for(etc; i++)` works!