# Fast way to find an ascii character in long integers using bitwise operations?

Tags: c, micro-optimization

I'm making a strchr implementation and trying to optimize my code to use the 64bit properties of my machine. So, I' converting my strings to long integers, thus comparing 8 chars at a time.

Currently, I have :

```
int    has_char(unsigned long word, unsigned long c)
{
    if((word & 0xFF00000000000000) == (c << 56) ) return (1);
    if((word & 0x00FF000000000000) == (c << 48))  return (1);
    if((word & 0x0000FF0000000000) == (c << 40))  return (1);
    if((word & 0x000000FF00000000) == (c << 32))  return (1);
    if((word & 0x00000000FF000000) == (c << 24))  return (1);
    if((word & 0x0000000000FF0000) == (c << 16))  return (1);
    if((word & 0x000000000000FF00) == (c << 8))   return (1);
    if((word & 0x00000000000000FF) == c)          return (1);
    return (0); /* Not found, returning 0 */
}

char    strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    const char      *curr;
    const long      *str;
    unsigned long    wd;

    str = (long *)s;
    while (1) {
        wd = *str;
        if (has_char(wd, (unsigned long)c)) {
            curr = (char *)str;
                while (*curr) {
                    if (*curr == (char)c)
                        return ((char *)curr);
                    curr++;
                }
        }
        if ((wd - 0x0101010101010101)
            & ~wd & 0x8080808080808080) /* End of string and character not found, exit */
            return (NULL);
    str++;
    }
}
```

It works well but my has_char is very inefficient, it tests 8 times for the character value. Is there a way to make a unique test (a mask ?) that will return 1 if the character is present in the word and 0 if it is not present ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You've already got the per-byte null test at the end of the loop. Simply build a mask from c<<0|c<<8|c<<16..c<<56 and XOR the source word by that, then any matching characters will be zero and you may re-use the null test.

Comment: Look at the SSE instruction sets

Comment: Your code does not work correctly if the string length is not a multiple of 8. And there are platforms where a `long` must be aligned on a 8-byte boundary, so you cannot cast any `char *` to an `unsigned long *`.

Comment: Hm, what happens if I get outside the 8-byte boundary ? Segmentation fault ? My computer is not complaining.. well, not yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very well, here is the precise code as requested:

```
// Return a non-zero mask if any of the bytes are zero/null, as per your original code
inline uint64_t any_zeroes(uint64_t value) {
    return (value - 0x0101010101010101) & ~value & 0x8080808080808080;
}

char *strchr(const char *s, int ch) {
    // Pre-generate a 64-bit comparison mask with the character at every byte position
    uint64_t mask = (unsigned char) ch * 0x0101010101010101;
    // Access the string 64-bits at a time.
    // Beware of alignment requirements on most platforms.
    const uint64_t *word_ptr = (const uint64_t *) s;

    // Search through the string in 8-byte chunks looking for either any character matches
    // or any null bytes
    uint64_t value;
    do {
        value = *word_ptr++:
        // The exclusive-or value ^ mask will give us 0 in any byte field matching the char
        value = any_zeroes(value) | any_zeroes(value ^ mask);
    } while(!value);

    // Wind-down and locate the final character. This may be done faster by looking at the
    // previously generated zero masks but doing so requires us to know the byte-order
    s = (const char *) --word_ptr;
    do {
        if(*s == (char) ch)
            return (char *) s;
    } while(*s++);
    return NULL;
}
```

Beware: Written off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code example and the detailed comments of what is going on !

Comment: Note that this implementation may read *beyond* the end-of-string, and [it has been noted this is *technically* UB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312340/why-does-this-implementation-of-strlen-work). It may or may not be "worse" in a 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, build a new variable c8 which is a c in every position.

```
unsigned long c8= (c << 56L) | ( c << 48L ) | ... | ( c << 8 ) | c ;
```

Do this once outside the loop so you're not recalculating.

Then XOR `c8` with `word`, and test each byte for zero.  To do this in parallel there are a few choices:

If you want to get ugly, we can start doing some parallel collapsing.  First lets fold all ones down into a single spot for each byte:

```
unsigned long ltmp ;
ltmp= word | (0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0 & ( word >> 4 )) ;
ltmp &= 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f ;
ltmp |= ( ltmp >> 2 ) ;
ltmp |= ( ltmp >> 1 ) ;
ltmp &= 0x0101010101010101 ;

return ( ltmp != 0x0101010101010101 ) ;
```

Or, comments are the following test:

```
((wd - 0x0101010101010101) & ~wd & 0x8080808080808080)
```

Is equivalent to all the previous operations.

BTW, the form:  `if (a) return 1 ;  return 0 ;` can just be written `return a ;` or `return a != 0 ;`

Comment: So in any case, I will have to test my `word` 8 times, if my char is present in any of the 8 places ?

Comment: @achedeuzot: No, you've already written a parallel zero test. Use it.

Comment: A faster way to do that is with `0x0101010101010101 * c`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm quite new to this, so could someone show me what the code or pseudocode should look like. Or is there is a good bitwise online calculator (I couldn't find any, usually it only gives the result without the operations) that would show me what is happening at every step of the way.

Comment: The test `if ((wd - 0x0101010101010101 & ~wd & 0x8080808080808080)`, which is already used in OP's code to test for the terminating zero, can also be used here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular pattern, but if it works, great.

Comment: @MartinR That's approximately what I tried to implement, what I have now in has_char is: `srch = (c << 56) | ( c << 48 ) | ... | ( c << 8 ) | c; res = word ^ srch; if ((res - 0x0101010101010101) & ~res & 0x8080808080808080) {return (1); }else { return (0); }`