# Is there a complete list of Implementation-Defined behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, standards

I was replying to a comment on my answer: [C job interview - casting and comparing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861807/3100771) and found that I could not find a complete list of what C++ deems "Implementation-Defined behavior." I'm aware there are 3 categories for this sort of thing: Undefined behavior, Implementation-Defined behavior, and Unspecified behavior; however it seems most discussions center around Undefined behavior, and when Implementation-Defined behavior is discussed, at most one example of it is given. In general I tend to write a lot of code that traipses into this area and I know what sort of behavior to expect; still I would like to be able to knowledgeably be able to comment on its validity. I would also like to throw out there that I think there is a lot of misdiagnoses in the community of operations being undefined, when really they are well defined by the platform.

Please note that I am not so much interested in how a given platform chooses to define such behavior, but rather to have a list of all behavior that falls into the “Implementation-Defined” category as defined by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard itself defines all the cases of *implementation defined behavior*, the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) has an `Index of implementation-defined behavior` at the end which provides topics and which page the topic is addressed on, for example:

> additional formats for time_get::do_get_date, 689
>
> alignment, 76
>
> alignment additional values, 76

In fact each compiler should document all the implementation defined behaviors and how it deals with them. For example here is [gcc's C++ Implementation-defined behavior section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Implementation.html) and [gcc's C Implementation-defined behavior](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Implementation.html). As far as I know the C++ standard does not unlike the *C99 draft standard* provide a reference for *unspecified* or *undefined* behavior. So you will have to resort to searching in the document for *undefined* and *unspecified* to find all instances.

The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) provides a reference for *unspecified*, *undefined*, and *implementation* defined behavior in `Annex J.1`, `J.2` and `J.3` respectively.

It is important to note that *undefined behavior* can be specified as well defined by an implementation but they do have to document it. In your specific example, it does look like you are violating [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922609/why-does-optimisation-kill-this-function/20956250#20956250) but your alternative suggestion to use *type-punning* is well defined since *C89*.